# WLAN device on Dell Inspiron not detected by Fedora 11

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, dell-inspiron, networkmanager, fedora-11

I recently installed Fedora 11 on a Dell Inspiron 14. I think it uses a Dell 802.11b/g Wireless LAN. Windows Vista can detect it but Fedora 11 can't. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your network card?

Comment: what model of inspiron?

Comment: Inspiron 14. How can I determine what my network card is?

Comment: What driver does Windows Vista use with this wireless card?

Comment: @fpmurphy, how can I determine that? Can it be found somewhere in `dmesg`?

Comment: You can probably get some data about the card in Fedora by typing lspci from a terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work! I followed @emgee's lead and used `lspci`. Executing `lspci` on my terminal showed this line along with several other lines:

> 0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom
>   Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01)

Googling **BCM4312** lead me to **[Broadcom Linux STA Driver](http://fedoramobile.org/fc-wireless/broadcom-linux-sta-driver)**. As stated in the intro:

> These packages contain Broadcom's IEEE
>   802.11a/b/g/n hybrid Linux® device driver for use with Broadcom's
>   BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4321-, and
>   BCM4322-based hardware. However, this
>   driver is known to support other
>   chipsets labelled differently (such as
>   the BCM4328.)

And then it was as simple as executing the following:

**Install the broadcom-wl packages**

> yum install broadcom-wl

**Loading the driver**

> modprobe wl

and restarting my machine.

Comment: Special thanks to @buba for following my progress.

Comment: Congratulations, I'm glad for you :)

Comment: Do you know if I could do that in Ubuntu? Or what the commands would be?

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect wired first, then get latest system/driver updates from Internet. It worked me few times.

There's a network manager called [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net), did you try it? And check [linuxwireless](http://linuxwireless.org) out, you can find the other managers and lots of information about wireless.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm gonna do. I'll post the results later.

Comment: The update didn't solve the problem.

Comment: try wicd too, one of my notebooks works only with it.

Comment: @buba, what's the model of your notebook the works with wicd?

Comment: hp pavilion dv5000 with amd sempron, it has ubuntu 8.10; i haven't tried with newer versions of ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the wicd package for Fedora 11 is unavailable at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked the two other network managers @ http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation ?