# Ubuntu 9.10 wireless problem

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I finally took the plunge and updated to ubuntu 9.10. Now my wireless doesn't work. I am using a dell inspiron 1545 with the broadcom sta driver.  I also cannot get any of my other drivers working (ati video card driver).

Update: Ubuntu partition just got erased after some interesting package installation. Going to try and re-install

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How do I get wireless?

Comment: Clean install or in-place update?

Answer (score 1):

Check this question and answers out: [WLAN device on Dell Inspiron not detected by Fedora 11](https://superuser.com/questions/53900/)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [backports software source](http://mynerditorium.blogspot.com/2009/11/having-ubuntu-910-wifi-problems.html) has solved the wifi issue for many people.

Answer (score 0):

```
I also cannot get any of my other drivers working (ati video card driver).
```

Have you followed the steps mentioned in [Ubuntu HowTo?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

> I am using a dell inspiron 1545 with
>   the broadcom sta driver.

Please provide more info on the Wireless - regarding chipset/model details.

Comment: How do I find that information?

Comment: I did follow the steps on the Ubuntu HowTo as well